# .NET 2 application caching HttpRuntime

Tags: c#, caching, .net-2.0

I have a question about using the .NET HttpRuntime object for caching in a windows form environment. I noticed, using .NET I will need to instantiate the HttpRuntime object and I have a funny feeling this will cause issues.

I have a class which exposes a property which I want stored in cache. The problem is the class requires instantiation and within its constructor I create an instance of HttpRuntime object. Will this cause issues? Will I have multiple instances of caching?

```
    public class Foo
    {
      public Foo()
      {
        System.Web.Runtime.HttpRuntime httpRuntime = new System.Web.Runtime.HttpRuntime();
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, Onam.

Comment: The HttpRuntime requires the application to be hosted in a web server process. Why would you need the HttpCache for a Windows app?

Comment: In .NET 2 there isn't a caching mechanism like System.Runtime.Cache, this is a .NET 4 feature. Searching the web only presents me with results stating to use the HttpRuntime cache.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512343/generic-cache-mechanism-for-net?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

`HttpRuntime` has a property `Cache`, but this property is static. Static means that all instances of `HttpRuntime` share that property. Er better said: The whole applicaties use the same property, so that `Cache` instance is shared by your whole application.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but if the app is installed as a per machine basis I imagine the cache will only be visible to this machine only? For example, both MACHINE_1 and MACHINE_2 has my app installed is the HttpRuntime cache shared on both machines?

Comment: That is totally correct. Each machine has one instance of your application. And each application instance has its own cache instance.